# How can I check the internal id of vertices and edges in the Java API in Galaxybase Database?

Tags: graph-databases

I’m using a graph database called Galaxybase (v3.4.1).
How can I check the internal id of vertices and edges in the Java API?

I did not find a way to check the internal id. I can't find the English technical documentation in the English official website.
(I know that I should tag specifically "galaxybase" but there's no tag of it. Sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding how to get the internal id of vertices:

The internal id of vertices can be queried by types and pk: getVertexIdByPK;
After calling the method of inserting a vertex, the return value also contains the internal id of the vertex.

Regarding how to get the internal id of edges:

1. the internal id of the edge can be found in the return value after calling the method that inserts the edge;
2. you need to look up the edge object before you can get the internal id of the edge from the edge object.